# MikTeX Setup Widzard No Reponse

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9, miktex-update

I am using Windows 10. I clicked download MiKTeX installer from here https://miktex.org/download.

After I clicked on several options (like whether I perfer A4 or letter), I click start and this window pops up:

[image]

If I click yes, then the window closes itself and nothing happens. No installation is started and the folder MiKTeX does not exist. What am I supposed to do to install MikTeX? According to online videos the installation should start right now.

Comment: Try right click the installer and "run as admin".

Comment: This works! Thank you very much!

Comment: Ack, no wonder I had to install it in appdata on my new computer!  Now, do I want to lose all my packages and documents again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MikTeX requires admin privileges to be installed on all users, thus you should run the installer as admin by right click on it and in the menu that has opened click on "run as admin".