# MikTex breaks when updating packages the first time

Tags: miktex, miktex-update

In Windows 10 I've reinstalled MikTex (last version got corrupted somehow) using the gui installer.
As soon as I have it installed, I check for updates.
There are 104 packages to update, so I set the update process going in the console. It makes it through the first few, then gets stuck at 8% installing miktex-config-2.9.

Windows Task Manager shows the process as suspended. There's 18GB free on my installation drive, so I don't think it's running out of space.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I am unsure how to use MikTex (I used TeXLive) but have you tried running the GUI installer as admin? Right click, more, `run as administrator` and see if it works then. Otherwise, hope someone else can answer!

Comment: Did you download the latest MikTeX package? Updating 104 packages sounds as if you are reinstalling a previously downloaded package. Then deleting MikTeX (or any program on Windows) always leaves residues. After deleting restart your computer twice or more. Not sure if it is a `Voodoo` thing, but apparently some of those residues are deleted then. Check the `Local` and `Roaming` maps in your `Appdata` map to see whether MikTeX is deleted from those. Also check the `Registry` for remaining keys and delete those.

Comment: Depending on what antivirus and firewall software you’re using, you may have to temporarily disable that. Sometimes the update is interrupted by either a faulty virus check or by blocking the url in the firewall. I know it sounds stupid, but hey it’s Microsoft … 

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669559/miktex-setup-widzard-no-reponse

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I tried again, cleaning the registry and rebooting twice. A clean install works, as before. I tried building some documents and they worked fine (installing some required packages on the fly). However, when I run the console (even in Admin mode) to update packages, it dies in the same place - 8%, miktex-config-2.9. As *alchemist* suggested, perhaps it's some weird virus checker that I can't disable (institution policy). I guess for now I can try to get along without updating packages...

Comment: SOLUTION: MikTex-Console was suspended in the task manager. Not sure if it made any difference, but I gave the console app permission to reach through the Windows Firewall. Then I went into Windows Task manager, Performance, Open Resource Manager and right clicked to unsuspend MikTex-Console. It resumed and finished with no other issues.