# MikTex internal error

Tags: miktex

I tried to install a LaTeX package via MikTex, but unfortunately I keep getting an error. It states that MikTeX has an internal error. If I copy the information to the clipboard it shows:

```
GENERAL MIKTEX INFORMATION
Date: 2023-04-04 13:49:16
MiKTeX: 2.9.7000
OS: Windows 10 Enterprise, 64-bit, build 19045
SharedSetup: yes
LinkTargetDirectory: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64
PathOkay: yes
LastUpdateCheckAdmin: 2019-04-13 13:17:12
LastUpdateAdmin: not yet
SystemAdmin: yes
RootPrivileges: yes
AdminMode: yes
Root0: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Invokers: 

Warning: the following problems were detected:
  1: It has been a long time since system-wide updates were checked.

ERROR DETAILS
Program: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-console_admin.exe
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\RestRemoteService.cpp:245
Error: MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
```

Because it states that it has been a long time since system-wide updates were checked, I tried updating MikTex, but I keep getting the same error. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Alternatively, is there another way to install package while circumventing MikTeX?

Thanks!

Comment: Check for updates in *admin* mode

Comment: Worst case you may need to uninstall and reinstall.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669559/miktex-setup-widzard-no-reponse

Comment: It's not worse case scenario to reinstall MikTeX. It is **actually necessary** to do so. MikTeX has changed a lot since 2019. According to the log the last time an update was done is almost exactly four years ago. Last year some core TeX components were extensively updated, which means packages were updated based on these core components won't run on a four year old base installation. Removing MikTeX and reinstalling a newly downloaded version is really easy. So just do that. You won't lose any documents.

Comment: You won't lose documents, but you will lose all your packages and manuals.